# SharePoint Search Service Error" The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available. "

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, crawl

We have SharePoint 2013 Standard Farm, which consists of 2 Web Front end and 2 App servers. Of which 2 WFE are hosting Query Processing Components and Index Components and 2 App Servers are hosting (Admin,Crawler, Content Processing,Analytic processing) services in my search topology.

2 App servers are hosting Central Admin site.

Now when i access central admin site from wfe1,wfe2,app1 server manage search application pages load up fine and i can access all its resources, but when i access it though App2 server Search admin pages i get following error messages:
*The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available.*

Then i grabbed that correlation id error was throwing i saw following logs in sharepoint:

> failed to get default collection for application SearchServiceApp
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   The service implementation object was not initialized or is not
>   available. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely
>   created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The service implementation object
>   was not initialized or is not available.
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) 
>       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)). StackTrace:  at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll:
>   (sig=2e6bd61f-fab5-45d9-95e0-1298f4064064|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb,
>   offset=131CE) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll: (offset=21BFD)
>
> A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application:
>   EndpointFailure Process Name: OWSTIMER Process ID: 9588 AppDomain
>   Name: DefaultDomain AppDomain ID: 1 Service Application Uri:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:0100e4ea804d4d9e908c4fe48cea7c41#authority=urn:uuid:ed27163bd08d402699c32e89ab9bc9ea&authority=http://wfe01.contoso.com:32844/Topology/topology.svc
>   Active Endpoints: 1 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint:
>   http://wfe02.contoso.com:32843/0100e4ea804d4d9e908c4fe48cea7c41/SearchService.svc

Comment: did you check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anupd/archive/2012/04/20/internal-server-exception.aspx  or http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/sharepoint-search-is-not-working.html